# Android listview custom rows

Tags: java, android, listview, row

I have a problem with a custom layout I've set for my listView. I have a button that adds elements to the listView and it uses a custom row but everytime I try to press the button to add it crashes. Can anyone suggest a solution on how to fix this? I'm pretty new to android btw.

Here's the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProjectCreateScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary_layout1);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    final ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListAdapter addAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_row,
            listItems);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(addAdapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listItems.add("New Project");
            ((ArrayAdapter) addAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent switchToEdit = new Intent(ProjectCreateScreen.this, teamCreateScreen.class);
            startActivity(switchToEdit);
        }
    });
}
```

}

The layout this activity uses:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rl">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/AddProject"
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="StartProject"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addBtn"
    android:id="@+id/lv">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The custom row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/customRow"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it simply says that the program 'stopped working', nothing on logcat

Comment: You may not be getting all of your logcat messages, if it crashes there should be a log trace.

Comment: Try to change `ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_row, listItems);` to `ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_row, R.id.customRow, listItems);` . I think you need to refers the id of text in android resource

Comment: @Rami I just noticed that you posted your comment before the final edit on my answer.  Good eye!  I was busy running the code and I didn't see your comment.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks... I must admit that it wasn't easy to figure out the reason of the problem... +1 to your answer, for solving it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:  You need to provide `R.id.customRow` to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.

This should fix it:

```
 final ListAdapter addAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_row, R.id.customRow,
                listItems);
```

With your original code, I added some data to the ArrayList, and got this exception:

```
04-09 13:12:34.992  12418-12418/com.listviewtest.daniel.listviewtest E/ArrayAdapter﹕ You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
04-09 13:12:34.992  12418-12418/com.listviewtest.daniel.listviewtest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-09 13:12:34.992  12418-12418/com.listviewtest.daniel.listviewtest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41891da0)
04-09 13:12:35.012  12418-12418/com.listviewtest.daniel.listviewtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.listviewtest.daniel.listviewtest, PID: 12418
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Comment: It didn't help and the layouts are in the order they're supposed to be in it's just something about that custom_row layout and the adapter that I'm using that's keeping the program from working properly

Comment: the activity uses secondary_layout1, the listView uses custom_row

Comment: it worked perfectly when i used the simple_list_item1 but when i added the custom_row it's no longer doing it's thing

Answer (score 0):

There is no public method named StartProject in the Activity. Remove this attribute:

```
android:onClick="StartProject"
```

and fix the layout_below:

```
android:layout_below="@id/addBtn"
```

Comment: you're right it's no longer necessary but it didn't fix the problem :/

Comment: remove the "+" from layout_below

Comment: why does that need fixing? The listView is supposed to be below the button

Comment: once again, removing the '+' doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_row, listItems);`

to

`ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_row, R.id.customRow, listItems);`

Look at [ArrayAdapter constructor params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]))